# Adaptive product filters for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

**1.**
I want to create a filter with adaptive product attributes, in woocommerce.

Example: I am in product category A, I select the value red from the color filter attribute. After this, only red products are shown, but also from this point I need to show in the filters only attributes which only red-color products have.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I tried looping all red products and get their attributes, so I can hide all other unnecessary attributes. Evidently, this solution is not efficient at all.

**2.** Also, is there any DB query to return "All attributes of products under category A / subcategory AA ..." ?

*Clarification:*

- An attribute is a taxonomy and an attribute value is a term.
- `color` is taxonomy and `red` is a term
- all updates are done with ajax and json

Comment: Stackoverflow works best by asking one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I find both questions related to the main issue, trying to make my problem as clear as possible. But again, thank you for the feedback, it is really appreciated. You have no idea how good this is for us newbies who try to login on stackoverflow and follow the rules, instead of just posting anonymously.

Comment: I didn't want to say that they would not be related or wouldn't make complete sense for you to ask, however Stackoverflow is not a problem posting board / forum in such a sense. So the only little thing I just wanted to mention is that if you would like to get useful results here on site, it normally pays to ask one concrete programming question at a time. That's all. For your two questions, I perfectly understand them and I think they are real questions but I find them hard to answer as they seem quite broad. You can start with an in memory implementation and then optimize it for speed.

Comment: Posting code for this question would be kinda useless, since the problem lies in the logic / pseudocode. It's true that the question is a little broad, but I tried anyway, thinking  that somebody else had similar situation and found the solution.

Comment: I quickly looked in the woocommerce db layout. So far I think you need to do this in memory anyway as the information is encoded inside wordpress database fields that you can not query directly. Last time I looked Wordpress still uses seralize/unserialize for meta-data which is not support by Mysql (JSON would nowadays and would also suffice for Wordpress [to the general extend] but it's not used.).